# Retrieving serialno of device

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, serial-number

I'm unable to select `serialno` from `Win32_DiskDrive`.  When I'm debugging it is showing me "NOT FOUND"

Code given as below:

```
string serialno="";
ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM     Win32_DiskDrive");

foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisks.Get())
{
  serialno = moDisk["SerialNumber"].ToString();

  dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "SerialNo";
  dataGridView1.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = serialno;
  row.Cells[4].Value = dataGridView1.Columns[4].DataPropertyName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code - based on `Win32_PhysicalMedia`

```
  var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");
   foreach(ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
   {
       var serialno = wmi_HD["SerialNumber"].ToString();
   }
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394346(v=vs.85).aspx